# I cannot shutdown clients from windows server 2012?

Tags: windows, batch-file, server, group-policy

I have few  windows 7 clients whom i need to reboot from windows server . i tried to setup a group policy

Action-create ,Name- Auto shut ,Account-NT/System,Action-shutdown.exe Trigger:4.00 AM :daily

This was applied for OU but it fails to deliver Can someone points where did i went wrong here and how to do it properly??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you consider using the command shutdown with the /m switch?

You can create a batch script will all machines you want to reboot

```
@echo off
for %%a in (computer1 computer2 computer3) do (
  shutdown /r /f /m \\%%a /t 30
)
```

and create a task that executes the script.

```
schtasks /create /SC DAILY /ST "04:00" /TN "task-name" /RL HIGHEST /TR "script-name"/F
```

Comment: i have three computers with names operation1,printing2,sec-admin .  Now i have created a batch file                                                            @echo off
for %%a in (operation1 printing2 secretary) do (
  shutdown /r /f /m \\%%a /t 30
)